# libvirt + qemu PCI passthrough and NVIDIA drivers not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, virtualization, qemu, pci, additional-drivers

I've setup a virtual machine with NVIDIA graphics card passthrough, and
after installing necessary drivers, the LightDM session doesn't start (I can see the greeter, but the user session doesn't start).

The machine's XML definition in libvirt is following:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='8' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
  <name>Ubuntu</name>
  <uuid>63f0800e-73f8-27ac-59a0-791fc68f7e25</uuid>
  <description>None</description>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-xenial'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
    <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough'>
    <topology sockets='1' cores='2' threads='1'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='abm'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pdpe1gb'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='rdrand'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='f16c'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='osxsave'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pdcm'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='xtpr'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='tm2'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='est'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='vmx'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ds_cpl'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='monitor'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='dtes64'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pbe'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='tm'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ht'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ss'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='acpi'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ds'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='vme'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/virtualstorage/vms/Ubuntu.img'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/virtualstorage/iso/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='ide0-1-1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:40:2b:aa'/>
      <source network='default' bridge='virbr0'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/0'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/0'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/0'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0'>
      <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='16384' heads='1'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <driver name='vfio'/>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <alias name='hostdev0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <driver name='vfio'/>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x1'/>
      </source>
      <alias name='hostdev1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x1'/>
    </hostdev>
    <memballoon model='none'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-vga'/>
    <qemu:arg value='none'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

Installed NVIDIA driver is NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.57.

```
dmesg | grep -i NVIDIA:

[    1.263194] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    1.266276] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.330297] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 247
[    1.330312] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  367.57  Mon Oct  3 20:37:01 PDT 2016
[    1.407850] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  367.57  Mon Oct  3 20:32:57 PDT 2016
[    1.424992] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000006] Loading driver
[    2.078662] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.1/sound/card0/input6
[    2.078733] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.1/sound/card0/input7
[    2.078794] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.1/sound/card0/input8
[    2.078832] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.1/sound/card0/input9
```

Thanks in advance.